# htaccess rewrite but query parameter always missing

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to redirect all:

```
example.com/{anything}
```

to:

```
example.com/index.php?q={anything}
```

But when I try:

```
example.com/aaa?param=xxx
```

I only got 'aaa' in the 'q' parameter, and the '?param=xxx' is lost. why? and how to keep it?

my current rule is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?a=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: _“I only got 'aaa' in the 'q' parameter”_ - did you expect `?param=xxx` to become part of the `a` parameter value as well? That is not how it works, `$1` did not contain that to begin with – RewriteRule matches on the URL _path_ only, you can not capture any query string contents there. But you should not need to either, `param` is not “lost”, it still gets passed to your script the same way it was before. Because you used the `QSA` flag, old and new query string will be merged. _Effectively_, this will be the same as if you had called `index.php?a=aaa&param=xxx` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test you actually do not get the param? For me, the param is not visible in the URL, but it it indeed passed.

I simply used this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ip.php?q=$1 [QSA]
```

And tried this on top of ip.php:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['q'])) {
        echo "PASSED: ".$_GET['q'];
}
?>
```

In this case, when I visit

```
mypage.com/SOMETHING
```

it seems it stays there, but $_GET param 'q' is set to SOMETHING. 
Without the above rewrite rules you will get 500 internal error usually.

Also check your server mod_rewrite rules etc. for certain specifics.

Comment: hello have try mypage.com/SOMETHING?param=aaa   ?